# C# .NET Write XML File from SQL Dataset with Custom Schema

Tags: c#, .net, xml, dataset, schema

I have the following code in C# Visual Studio 2010.

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Database\\db.mde";
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Customer";
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
connection.Open();
adapter.Fill(ds, "Test Table");
connection.Close();
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
dataGridView1.DataMember = "Test Table";
ds.WriteXml("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\testfile.XML");
```

Now it does everything I want but I need to slightly modify the format of the XML file when it exports. Can this be easily done? I gather I need to provide a schema file which is fine but I'm not sure how to implement it with the dataset.

Currently the XML looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Test_x0020_Table>
    <name>Customer1</name>
    <address>25 Big St</address>
    <suburb>Sydney NSW</suburb>
    <contact>Fred Nurk</contact>
    <phone>11 1111 1111</phone>
  </Test_x0020_Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

... but I want it to look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Customers>
    <name>Customer1</name>
    <address>25 Big St</address>
    <suburb>Sydney NSW</suburb>
    <contact>Fred Nurk</contact>
    <phone>11 1111 1111</phone>
</Customers>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first node is the name of your table.

You can change this by setting a name on your DataSet.

*DataSet ds = new DataSet("**Customers**"); //plural*

---

The inner node is the record.

You can change this by specifying the name when you fill the adapter.

*adapter.Fill(ds, "**Customer**"); //singular*

---

This will give you a result like:

```
 
<Customers>
  <Customer>
    <name>Customer1</name>
    <address>25 Big St</address>
    <suburb>Sydney NSW</suburb>
    <contact>Fred Nurk</contact>
    <phone>11 1111 1111</phone>
  </Customer>
</Customers>
```

This means if you return multiple results you would end up with:

```
 
<Customers>
  <Customer>
    <name>Customer1</name>
    <address>25 Big St</address>
    <suburb>Sydney NSW</suburb>
    <contact>Fred Nurk</contact>
    <phone>11 1111 1111</phone>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
    <name>Customer1</name>
    <address>25 Big St</address>
    <suburb>Sydney NSW</suburb>
    <contact>Fred Nurk</contact>
    <phone>11 1111 1111</phone>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
    <name>Customer1</name>
    <address>25 Big St</address>
    <suburb>Sydney NSW</suburb>
    <contact>Fred Nurk</contact>
    <phone>11 1111 1111</phone>
  </Customer>
</Customers>
```

You can't have a single "Customer" because when you write the XML it's formatting it as "Table" with "Records".

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this :

```
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ds.WriteXml(ms);
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(ms);

            // change XML using doc

            doc.Save("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\testfile.XML");                
        }
```

--edit--

Here is a little test that I created on how you can transform your xml using LINQ to XML:

```
    private void XmlTest()
    {
        String xml = "<NewDataSet><Test_x0020_Table><name>Customer1</name><address>25 Big St</address><suburb>Sydney NSW</suburb><contact>Fred Nurk</contact><phone>11 1111 1111</phone></Test_x0020_Table></NewDataSet>";

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        XElement element = doc.Descendants("Test_x0020_Table").First();
        XElement newElement = new XElement("Customers", element.Descendants());

        MessageBox.Show(newElement.ToString());
    }
```

Use above code to manipulate your xml and save it using `doc.Save()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not 100% sure how that would work. I updated the original question to include some more info. How does XDocument know where to put the data in between the tags?

Comment: @user526549 - I think @decyclone is suggesting that you use the XDocument methods to manually manipulate the XML generated by WriteXML into the format that you want.  Looks like WriteXML gets you most of the way there - all you need is to replace the two outer tags with your Customer tag.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Have you guys got any example links at all? I can't seem to get this to work. I've tried adding doc.Add(new XElement("customers")); but that doesn't work. I tried a few other different combinations but I'm not getting anything. By the way I had to add ms.Position = 0; in between the ds.WriteXML and the XDocument doc for it to work for me. Other than that I'd get a root element is missing error.

Comment: Ok I've given the dataset a name to add customers as the root element. I now have <Table> which needs to be removed. I want to the records to display without the <Table></Table> at the start and end of each record. I tried this XElement table = doc.Element("Table");
table.Remove(); but that errors out. doc.save is underneath that. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your XML will always be of a structure similar to

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Test_x0020_Table>
    <name>Customer1</name>
    <address>25 Big St</address>
    <suburb>Sydney NSW</suburb>
    <contact>Fred Nurk</contact>
    <phone>11 1111 1111</phone>
  </Test_x0020_Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

You can do something like this:

```
string XMLPath = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\testfile.XML";

XDocument XMLPreModification = new XDocument.Load(XMLPath);
XDocument XMLModified = new XDocument;

XMLDoified.Add(New XElement("Customers", XMLPreModification.Descendants.Descendants()));

XMLModified.Save(XMLPath);
```

This is just making a new XDocument adding a Customer Element and inserting the Nodes you want into that element, then saving it out to the file.